# changing navigation header image size when scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an image in which i want to change it's size when scrolling down and return it's original size when scrolling up ... something similar to this:

[image]

so i have imageview and then scroll view .. when scrolling down the imageview height shrink and it's image change and when scrolling back to top the imageview height returns and the big image returns as well ..

how can i achieve this? is there any library or something that helps me with this?

Comment: do you like to use any library?

Comment: @V_rohit yeah its okay as long as it does what i need

Comment: https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView you can use this link

Comment: and here you can find lots of awesome things https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios

Comment: @V_rohit Thanks alot!!!!! in the second link where do i find what i need? under which section?

Comment: suppose you need stretchy header so it is used in tableview and collection so just click on that and enjoy :)

Comment: @V_rohit many many thanks!!!

Comment: anytime haha :)